# how to spread with reduce by recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

here is for for loop method and the result i want is same like this for the below this code also

```js
function reduce (dollars) {
  let arr = [];
  let change = [10000,5000,2000,1000,500,200,100,50,20,10,1];

  if(dollars === 0) return arr
  for(key of change){
    if(key <= dollars) return arr.concat(key).concat(reduce (dollars -= key));
  }
}

console.log(reduce(900))
console.log(reduce(9000))
```

how to use reduce and using the spread syntax in recursion way,
i got some error and the concat function is called not function when i use `reduce` by recursively 
here is the code ,

```js
function reduce(dollar) {
  let change = [10000,5000,2000,1000,500,200,100,50,20,10,1];
  if(dollar === 0) return c
  let c = change.reduce((ar, el) => {
    if(dollar >= el) {
      return ar.concat(el).concat(reduce(dollar-=el))
    }
  }, [])
}
let [ one, two, three] = [10020,9000,900];
console.log(reduce(one));
console.log(reduce(two));
console.log(reduce(three));
```

the output for the reduce(one) is `[ 10000, 20 ]`

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the reduce handler always returns the array, seeing the handler expects `ar` to be an array. If `undefined` is returned in the reduce handler, that will be passed through to the next reduce iteration as `ar`, which is the cause of the error you're getting.

Also, ensure `c` is defined before returning it, or revise the code as shown below to avoid the need for `c` completely:

```js
function reduce(dollar) {

  let change = [10000,5000,2000,1000,500,200,100,50,20,10,1];
  
  /* if dollar === 0 then return [] */
  if (dollar === 0) return [];      
    
  /* Return reduced result (ie "c" in original code) */
  return change.reduce((ar, el) => {
        
    /*
    While el deducted from dollar yields positive value,
    */
    while (dollar - el >= 0) {
      
      /*
      then decrement dollar amout by current el and,
      */
      dollar -= el;  
      
      /*
      add el to current result
      */
      ar = ar.concat(el)
    }
    
    /*
    Return resulting ar array
    */
    return ar;
    
  }, [])
}

let [ one, two, three ] = [ 10020, 9000, 900 ];
console.log(reduce(one));
console.log(reduce(two));
console.log(reduce(three));
```

Comment: ok you just edited it, so for that case , we should make conditions in reduce ? and we cant use spread for that?

Comment: @ZumDummi just updated answer based on my understanding of your post - does that help?

Comment: for the output two and three not like i want, it should to be ` [ 5000, 2000, 2000 ]` for tow and` [ 500, 200, 200 ]` for three

Comment: @ZumDummi please consider accepting this answer if you have found it useful :-)